# double bracket does not work for -d and -f commands

Tags: bash

```
if [[ -d "$HOME/test_bash/$KIT.stat_$KIT" ]; then
echo $KIT
else
mkdir $KIT.stat_$KIT
fi
if [[ "14"=="14" ]]; then 
echo "FOO"
fi
```

The first if statement with [[ -d does not work, but the second if statement "14"=="14" does work when I use the bash test.sh command. However, if I replace the first if statement '[[' with a single bracket '[', it works. Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a single closing `]` on your first line.

Comment: Also missing spaces around the operator in the second `if` (`[[ "14"=="14" ]]` should be `[[ "14" == "14" ]]`).

Comment: Yup - if he wants to compare the strings, anyway. ;-)

Comment: @vkaul11, yeah, but it's not comparing anything.  Change one of those `14`s to something else and you'll see.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Thanks. What is the reason for that? In bash variable assignment should not have a space and operator needs a space? For example DIR = dir is not valid and DIR=dir is valid.

Comment: read the bash man page -- look for the `test` command. You'll read that when given only a single argument (such as `14==14`) the test command returns true if the argument is non-empty.